# Runtime Permissions not working

Tags: android, runtime-permissions

This is my code in OnCreate() method :

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(thisActivity,
            Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(thisActivity,
        Manifest.permission.RECIEVE_SMS)) {

} else {

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
            new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},1);
}
```

And in my onRequestPermissionsResult() method :

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

              init();
}else{
         finish();
 }
```

And my Manifest file has the following permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
```

But i'm not getting the dialog asking for the permission and i can't figure out the problem?

Comment: Check under Settings->Apps->(Your app name)->Permissions to see if the app already has the permission granted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your app targeting Android 6.0 and above than add runtime permission

**Beginning in Android 6.0 (API level 23), users grant permissions to apps while the app is running, not when they install the app**

add runtime permission using below code for READ_SMS

```
String permission = Manifest.permission.READ_SMS;
int grant = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission);
if (grant != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    String[] permission_list = new String[1];
    permission_list[0] = permission;
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permission_list, 1);
}
```

and than handle result like this

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Toast.makeText(AccountClass.this,"permission granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
             // perform your action here

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(AccountClass.this,"permission not granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: you are asking for **READ_CONTACTS** permission and this permission not added in manifest file

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(AddnewPhotoActivity.this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(AddnewPhotoActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

            } else {

                isPermissionGranted(true);
            }
```

**isPermissionGranted(boolean); ====>  Method call**

```
public void isPermissionGranted(boolean permission) {
        if (permission) {


           //Your Operation


        } else {

            Toast.makeText(this, "Permission not granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

**onRequestPermissionsResult**

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) {
            if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                isPermissionGranted(true);

            } else

            {
                isPermissionGranted(false);
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: It still doesn't show the dialog asking for permission? and grantResults is passing PERMISSION_DENIED